# Visual Studio Code no reconoce las tildes

Tags: codificación, vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen VSC me muestra ese caracter raro en vez de la "ó". Lo peor de todo es que sobreescribe esa palabra y se queda como en la imagen. Cuando abro el proyecto en mi eclipse se muestra con el caracter raro.

Necesito ayuda para configurarlo y que no haga eso. Gracias.

Comment: En mi caso simplemente configuré ISO-8859-1 en las preferencias de VSC y volví a abrir el archivo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Has abierto el archivo con una codificación diferente de la que se usó cuando fue guardado.

Fíjate en la barra de estado de Visual Studio Code, donde muestra la codificación. Posiblemente verás "UTF-8".

[image: Codificación]

Pulsando en ella te permitirá cambiarlo por otra, para lo cual te dará a elegir entre "volver a abrir con encoding" o "guardar con encoding". Elige la primera opción y prueba "Western Windows 1252"

Una vez lo ha convertido y lo ves correctamente en el editor, puedes elegir con qué codificación guardarlo, pulsando de nuevo en el mismo sitio y eligiendo "Guardar con encoding". Elige utf8 para la máxima compatibilidad con otras plataformas (y con el propio VS Code, para cuando lo abras de nuevo).

Comment: Si lo tenía en UTF-8. Entonces, seguí tus indicaciones y todo bien. Pero cuando vuelvo a abrir otro archivo tengo que volver a ejecutar los mismo pasos. ¿Cómo hago para que sea predeterminado?

Comment: En la configuración general es el valor de `"files.encoding"`. Pero yo no lo cambiaría a `windows 1252` de forma general, pues entonces en cuanto abras un archivo utf8 lo verías mal (y tendrías que hacer la conversión). Y UTF8 es el estándar moderno y el más probable de encontrar. Ahora bien, si estás trabajando en unos archivos que son todos con codificación windows puede interesarte cambiar esa opción general hasta que acabes esta tarea y luego volver a ponerlo en utf8. También tienes una opción `"files.autoGuessEncoding"` que puede serte más útil.

Comment: @abulafia sos genial!! `"files.autoGuessEncoding"` absolutamente útil!

Answer (score 4):

La opción de [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206354/28035) es muy util, pero que tal si tenemos un equipo de trabajo en distintos países y con distintos [***IDE'S***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado)??

Podemos definir a nivel de repositorio un archivo de configuración para evitar estos errores, en la raiz de tu repositorio crea un archivo cuyo nombre sea **`.editorconfig`** y defines que tipo de codificación quieres usar; en tu caso el archivo quedara de la siguiente manera:

```
charset = utf-8
```

de igual forma se pueden hacer muchas cosas interesantes con este archivo te invito a visitar la web [**editorconfig.org**](https://editorconfig.org/)